# how to use map, forkjoin and mergemap

Tags: angular, observable

I need to make different API calls.

1st API call returns `info` list of object which has `userId`, `propertyId`

for each item I need to get `userInfo` and `propertyinfo` based on the ID's returned from first API call.

at last it has to return `info`, `userInfo`, `popertyInfo`.

I would like to write once subscribe method to make these API calls in `ts` file.

`this.service.getInfo().subscribe((data) => {console.log('should list all the information')}` //should print info, userInfo, propertyInfo

I have the following code:

```
getInfo() {
  return this.http.get().pipe(
    mergeMap((info) => {

    })
}
```

firstAPI:

```
[
    {
        info: 'some info 1',
        userId: 1,
        propertyId: 4,
    },
    {
        info: 'some info 2',
        userId: 2,
        propertyId: 5,
    },
    {
        info: 'some info 3',
        userId: 3,
        propertyId: 6,
    },
];
```

each second api: (get userId from each array element of first API call)

```
{
    userName: 'asdasd',
    age: 34
}
```

each third api call: (get propertyId from each array element of first API call)

```
{
    propertyName: 'adasd',
    otherProps: ''
}
```

final response should be something like

```
res = 
[
    {
        info: 'some info 1',
        userId: 1,
        propertyId: 4,
        userName: 'asdasd',
        age: 34,
        propertyName: 'adasd',
        otherProps: ''
    },

    {
        info: 'some info 2',
        userId: 2,
        propertyId: 5,
        userName: 'a',
        age: 34,
        propertyName: 'b',
        otherProps: ''
    },
    ...
    ...
]
```

Comment: For me, it is unclear the final result. Can you provide mocks for info(first response), second response data and output data.

Comment: @ВалерийГерасимов I have updated my question, have a look and please help me if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it next way:

```
getInfo() {
    return this.http.get().pipe(
        mergeMap((info: {userId: number, propertyId: number}[]) => {
            const userIdRequests = info.map(item => this.http.get(`/second-api/${item.userId}`));
            const propertyIdRequests = info.map(item => this.http.get(`/third-api/${item.propertyId}`));
            const userIdData$ = forkJoin(userIdRequests);
            const propertyIdData$ = forkJoin(propertyIdRequests);
            return forkJoin([userIdData$, propertyIdData$]).pipe(
                map(([userIdList, propertyIdList]) => {
                    const result = [];
                    info.forEach((infoItem, index) => {
                        const resItem = {
                            ...infoItem,
                            ...userIdList[index],
                            ...propertyIdList[index]
                        };
                        result.push(resItem);
                    });
                    return result;
                })
            )
        })
    )
}
```

Here mergeMap is used to return new observable instead of first one.

forkJoin is used three times to wait for all requests ends up, and also it is used to group requests(by type of API call, user or property)

map function is used to convert three arrays we have`(info, userIdInfo, propertyIdInfo)` into expected result.

I have made assumptions about your API call URLs. And variable names are fare from your domain. But the key concept is show.